# How to supply a list of URLs for brute forcing in Nmap?

Tags: nmap

Does anyone know how to supply a list of URLs for http-brute.nse script? It looks like I'm limited to only supplying a list of IP addresses and through the http-brute.path argument I can provide one path.

Any simple way to just supply a list of known http authentication URLs?

I've looked at the NSE scripts manual and couldn't find anything making it that easy.

Something like:
ie; nmap  --script http-brute --script-args=urls.txt

Answer (score 0):

Nmap doesn't provide a way to directly supply a list of URLs to the http-brute script. But you can do it with a little bash script such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read URL; do
  nmap --script http-brute -p 80 --script-args 'http-brute.path=${URL}' host
done < urls.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to supply a list of URLs is using `xargs` to run sequentially `nmap` for each domain in a file.

```bash
cat domains.txt | xargs -I{} nmap -sT {}
```

Using the flag `-I{}` allows substitution on `{}` to represent a single domain.